# SSH: what is the difference between user:~ and user:#

Tags: ssh

I have come across someone who when using ssh after logging in uses the command 'cd /' as soon as they log in. I'm trying to find out what the difference is and cannot really find an answer anywhere. I have added a picture to hopefully clear up the exact thing I am looking for:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgTdq.png)

Sorry if this is a stupid question but it has been on my mind for a while now and I would like to know the difference.

Thank you

Comment: Your title misrepresents the image, which simply shows a prompt that displays the current working directory. As for why the user execute `cd /`, there's no particularly interesting explanation beyond "they plan on doing something in the root directory".

Comment: thank you, and sorry I'm pretty new to using ssh and just trying to learn all that I can about it

Answer (score 0):

`cd /` refers to change directory to root whereas `cd ~` refers to change directory to the home directory, typically its path is `/home/$USER/`.

The Home directory can be understood as the files or directories which have read, write permission (755) to normal users whereas the root directory consists of files and directories which don't have access to normal users, however you can access them through super-user access (sudo privileges).

Answer (score 0):

```
~  current user home directory
~user1 home directory of user1
/ root directory
```